# Android Pie(9) java.net.SocketTimeoutException from a subdomain using mobile network

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit also tried using OkHttp - with network security config properly added in the AndroidManifest, it happens only on Android 9 Pie devices such as Google Pixel and Samsung - response sometimes works on WIFI but never on mobile network.

Exception: failed to connect to www.subsomain3.subsomain2.subsomain1.domain.com/X.X.X.X (port 443) from /X.X.X.X (port 37910) after 9999ms